# Jquery dynamic updation of the values

Tags: jquery

In my application am using jquery.In that i am generating dynamic jquery dropdowns.say for example the id will be like "dropdown1", "dropdown2" etc.The values of these dropdowns are similar.when am selecting a value from a dropdown the same should be removed from all the other dropdowns.Can anyone give me a helpfull solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="ddm">
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
</ul>

<ul id="dropdown2" class="ddm">
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.ddm li').click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var txt = me.text();
    var id = me.parent().attr('id');
    $('.ddm').not('#' + id + '').each(function(i) {
    $('li:contains(' + txt + ')', this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: hi friend, here you dont give any idea, how u generate you list; .i.e. using `div` / `ul-li` or other. So I give an demo like my own. if you have something other spec you can comment me. i will try to solve.